# XAMPP - Rewrite Rule doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, url-rewriting

I am using XAMPP (Windows 7) and in httpd.conf I have:

- AllowOverride All
- LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (uncommented)

In *htdocs* directory I have subdirectory called **shop** where is my website. Inside *shop* I have one more subdirectory called **shirts** containing the file:

- shirts.php

To open it you just neet to enter the following url: http://localhost/shop/shirts/shirts.php

But, when I open just http://localhost/shop/shirts/ -  browser displays a directory listing, and I want it to open shirts.php.

So, inside **/shirts** directory I created the following **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/$ /shop/shirts/shirts.php
```

But it doesn't work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong, why is this not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try write this `DirectoryIndex index.php shirts.php`in your **.htaccess** file

Comment: Please specify where exactly in .htaccess to put this line. It might matter.

Comment: This works, thank you. I watch some video courses and do not understand why the author used `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/$ /shop/shirts/shirts.php` and that worked on his installation of XAMPP (localhost), but it doesnt work for me? Anyway, your answer solves my problem.